# Change the integer value coding of a factor in R

Tags: r

If I have the following vector:

```
x<-c("blue","green","green","blue","blue")
```

When converting to a factor I find the following:

`Factor w/ 2 levels "blue","green": 1 2 2 1 1`

I want to change the numbers `1 and 2` to `0 and 1`.

Can be done?

**Thank you very**

Comment: You can't change the integer coding as in `R`, the index starts from 1.  If you want the vector to change as such `as.integer(factor(x)) - 1`

Comment: But it ceases to be a factor to become numeric.

Some other solution and to be able to change the whole numbers.
But that has the factor properties.

Comment: Not clear why you want `R` to behave like `python`. `factor(x, levels = c('blue', 'green'), labels = 0:1)`

Comment: Because I need to export it to dta (stata) format, they ask me to have that configuration. Of 0 ta 1.